# Inequality for norms

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, normed-spaces

Let g(x, y) be function on $X\times Y$. Show that for all $p\geq q$
$$
\|\,\|g\|_{L^q(Y)}\,\|_{L^p(X)}\leq \|\,\|g\|_{L^p(X)}\,\|_{L^q(Y)}
$$
Thsnk you.

Comment: *What have you tried or thought about?*

Comment: I thought tht Jencene inequality would be halpful... But I did not suceed with it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: @Ma Ming: Thank you, but its only for $L_p$. I have $L_p$ and $L_q$ at the same inequality.

Comment: @Alex See the bottom there.

Comment: @MaMing More concretely?

Comment: @Alex http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski.27s_integral_inequality To show this, basically you can integrate the second variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Minkowski integral inequality states that for $ r \geq 1 $ and other appropriate conditions we have 
$$ \Bigl(\int_X \Bigl|\int_Y f(x,y)dy\Bigr|^r dx\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{r}} \leq \int_Y\Bigl(\int_X |f(x,y)|^rdx\Bigr)^{\frac{1}{r}} dy $$ 
So you substitute $ f = |g|^q,\ r = p/q $ obtain the inequality and then take $1/q $ power on both sides. This will end up exactly in $ \| \|g\|_{L^q(Y)}\|_{L^p(X)} \leq \| \|g\|_{L^p(X)}\|_{L^q(Y)} $

Comment: This is "the answer".